# Scrollbar doesnt resize for labels inside canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

This is my first attempt using objects, i don't fully understand yet. The immediate issue is that the scrollbar is not functioning. I'm not sure if i need to update the scrollbar config or what is going on. Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess, re, webbrowser


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master) 
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        #There must be a way to have canv, and sbar NOT be be global.
        global canv
        canv = Canvas(self)
        global sbar
        sbar = Scrollbar(self)
        canv.config(width=400, height=600)               
        canv.config(scrollregion = canv.bbox("all"))
        canv.config(highlightthickness=0)
        sbar.config(command=canv.yview)                   
        canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)             
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                     
        canv.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.create_widgets(canv)       


    def create_widgets(self, canv):
        x = Label(canv,text = "Repository Search: ")
        x.pack()
        self.person_ent = Entry(canv)
        self.person_ent.pack()

        Button(canv,
               text = "Search",
               command = self.tell_story
               ).pack()



    def callback(self, line):
        line = str(line)
        soft = re.sub("b'", "", line).split(' ', 1)[0]
        url = "https://packages.debian.org/jessie/" + soft
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)



    def tell_story(self):
        person = self.person_ent.get()
        bashCommand = "apt-cache search " + person
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        process
        for line in output.splitlines():
            link = Label(canv, text=line, foreground="#0000ff", cursor="hand1")
            link.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, line = line: self.callback(line))
            link.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Apt Repository Search")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The scrollbar won't scroll widgets that are added via `pack`. You must use the `create_window` method of the canvas.

Comment: I will try that, and post results. Thank you.